# Ios swift change type of results array

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

How can i change type of tableview results array.

```
var results: [Group] = []
```

now i use that viewcontroller for 2 purposes, same design and same table, but another results array.

Now i need to change it in this didSet:

```
var article:Article? {
    didSet {
        var results: [Article] = [] // something like this
        getArticleOrderData()
    }
}
```

when article is set, to change type of results array to `[Article]`.

Is that possible?

Or should i just make another and another viewcontroller in storyboard for articles?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but you can do something with anyobject and when you use the object, you set "as! Group" or "as! Article"...

Comment: Declare a protocol where both types conform to and use the protocol as collection type for the table view

Comment: Any example for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a protocol where both types conform to and use the protocol as collection type for the table view.

Very simple example:

```
protocol Resultable {
  var name : String {get set}
}

class Article : Resultable {
  var name = "article"
}

class Group : Resultable {
  var name = "group"
}

class MYTableViewController : UITableViewController {

  var results = [Resultable]()

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let result = results[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = result.name
    return cell
  }
}
```